# showing PDF file for restricted users

Tags: php

My website is build in PHP and i integrated stripe payment. If user payment through stripe is successful then i need to open a PDF file which is hosted
on same server where code is running.

Below is the code i am using to open PDF file:

```
$file = 'test.pdf';
$filename = 'test.pdf';
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
@readfile($file);
```

I don't want test.pdf file to be accessible directly. So if i change permissions of test.pdf to 777 then code runs and opens PDF file but it also enable anyone to open file through direct link. If i change permissions so that access to this file is restricted to code files then it is not opening the pdf file. How can i achieve this so that PDF file can be opened after successful stripe payment but not through direct URL.

Comment: Server-side permissions are nearly irrelevant: if you don‘t put the file into a directory that is publicly available through your webserver, its only available through your script. You should rather put some permission checks there

Comment: So what permissions should i put for folder which will contain pdf file ?

Comment: Choose that permission that allows your script to read them. This depends on which user your webserver runs with, which user writes the PDF files and which other applications run on that server.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the direct access of the file by a .htaccess (or vitual host configuration) with a 'Deny from all'. The 'readfile()' will work if the server user (www-data for example) has the read and execute rights on the pdf